# Collecting Attributes in XML using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, ruby-on-rails-2

I have this XML:

```
<RECEIPT receiptDate="2012-02-10T12:46:26.661Z" submissionFile="E.coli_ENT_WS.submission.xml" success="false">

  <EXPERIMENT alias="ENT 23" status="PUBLIC"/>
  <EXPERIMENT alias="WS 23" status="PUBLIC"/>
  <RUN alias="ENT 23" status="PUBLIC"/>
  <RUN alias="WS 23" status="PUBLIC"/><
  SAMPLE alias="ENT 23" status="PUBLIC"/>
  <SAMPLE alias="WS 23" status="PUBLIC"/>
  <STUDY alias="ENT 23" status="PUBLIC"/>
  <STUDY alias="WS 23" status="PUBLIC"/>
  <SUBMISSION alias="E.coli_ENT_WS"/>
  <MESSAGES>
    <ERROR> In run(ENT 23), the FC018_s_6_sequence_L70.txt.md5 not found </ERROR>
    <ERROR> In run(ENT 23) found the file format(Illumina_native_fastq), but requires SPOT_DESCRIPTOR information in the experiment(ENT 23)</ERROR>
    <ERROR>The Illumina_native_fastq file format required gzip compression for submission.</ERROR>
    <ERROR> FILE attribute quality_scoring_system is required</ERROR>
    <ERROR>Same file FC018_s_6_sequence_L70.txt found in Run(WS 23) has been used with other Run</ERROR>
    <ERROR> In run(WS 23), the FC018_s_6_sequence_L70.txt.md5 not found </ERROR>
    <ERROR> In run(WS 23) found the file format(Illumina_native_fastq), but requires SPOT_DESCRIPTOR information in the experiment(WS 23)</ERROR>
    <ERROR>The Illumina_native_fastq file format required gzip compression for submission.</ERROR>
    <ERROR> FILE attribute quality_scoring_system is required</ERROR>
    <INFO> VALIDATE action for the following XML: E.coli_ENT_WS.study.xml E.coli_ENT_WS.sample.xml E.coli_ENT_WS.experiment.xml E.coli_ENT_WS.run.xml      </INFO>
    <INFO>Inform_on_error is not filled in; auto populated from Submission account. </INFO>
    <INFO>Number of files in drop box = 2 &amp; Number of files in Submission = 1</INFO>
    <INFO>Deprecated element ignored: CENTER_NAME</INFO>
    <INFO>Deprecated element PROJECT_ID converted to RELATED_STUDY</INFO>
    <INFO>Deprecated element ignored: CENTER_NAME</INFO>
    <INFO>Deprecated element PROJECT_ID converted to RELATED_STUDY</INFO>
    <INFO> SPOT_DESCRIPTOR is missing</INFO><INFO> SPOT_DESCRIPTOR is missing</INFO>
    <INFO>Experiment (ENT 23) SPOTDESCRIPTOR is optional is null</INFO>
    <INFO>Experiment (WS 23) SPOTDESCRIPTOR is optional is null</INFO>
    <INFO> In run(ENT 23) file name (FC018_s_6_sequence_L70.txt) mentioned is not found among the submitted files</INFO>
    <INFO> In run(WS 23) file name (FC018_s_6_sequence_L70.txt) mentioned is not found among the submitted files</INFO>
  </MESSAGES>
  <ACTIONS>VALIDATE</ACTIONS>
  <ACTIONS>VALIDATE</ACTIONS>
  <ACTIONS>VALIDATE</ACTIONS>
  <ACTIONS>VALIDATE</ACTIONS>
  <ACTIONS>HOLD</ACTIONS>
</RECEIPT>
```

I am able to retrieve all the element tags mainly `EXPERIMENT`, `ERROR`, `INFO`, `ACTION`, `MESSAGE`.

What I would like to retrieve is the attributes from elements like `EXPERIMENT` and `RECEIPT`

I am using Nokogiri for my parsing.

My code is like this:

```
@req_test = %x[curl -F "SUBMISSION=@xml/#{@experiment.alias}.submission.xml" -F "STUDY=@xml/#{@experiment.alias}.study.xml" -F "SAMPLE=@xml/#{@experiment.alias}.sample.xml" -F "RUN=@xml/#{@experiment.alias}.run.xml" -F "EXPERIMENT=@xml/#{@experiment.alias}.experiment.xml" https://www-test.ebi.ac.uk/ena/submit/drop-box/submit/]
    @doc = Nokogiri::XML(@req_test) 

    # collecting all the errors
    @expt = @doc.xpath("//ERROR")

    # Collecting all the INFO
    @info = @doc.xpath("//INFO")
```

That was my controller. My View is something just for display:

```
<h3>This is the ERRORS Collected</h3>
<% for expt in @expt %>
<ul>
  <li><%= expt %><br \></li>
</ul>
<% end %>

<br \ >

<h3>This is the INFO Collected</h3>

<% for info in @info %>
<ul>
  <li><%= info %><br \></li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

and the application renders something like this:

```
This is the ERRORS Collected

    In run(ENT 23), the FC018_s_6_sequence_L70.txt.md5 not found

    In run(ENT 23) found the file format(Illumina_native_fastq), but requires SPOT_DESCRIPTOR information in the experiment(ENT 23)

    The Illumina_native_fastq file format required gzip compression for submission.

    FILE attribute quality_scoring_system is required

    Same file FC018_s_6_sequence_L70.txt found in Run(WS 23) has been used with other Run

    In run(WS 23), the FC018_s_6_sequence_L70.txt.md5 not found

    In run(WS 23) found the file format(Illumina_native_fastq), but requires SPOT_DESCRIPTOR information in the experiment(WS 23)

    The Illumina_native_fastq file format required gzip compression for submission.

    FILE attribute quality_scoring_system is required


This is the INFO Collected

    VALIDATE action for the following XML: E.coli_ENT_WS.study.xml E.coli_ENT_WS.sample.xml E.coli_ENT_WS.experiment.xml E.coli_ENT_WS.run.xml

    Inform_on_error is not filled in; auto populated from Submission account.

    Number of files in drop box = 2 & Number of files in Submission = 1

    Deprecated element ignored: CENTER_NAME

    Deprecated element PROJECT_ID converted to RELATED_STUDY

    Deprecated element ignored: CENTER_NAME

    Deprecated element PROJECT_ID converted to RELATED_STUDY

    SPOT_DESCRIPTOR is missing

    SPOT_DESCRIPTOR is missing

    Experiment (ENT 23) SPOTDESCRIPTOR is optional is null

    Experiment (WS 23) SPOTDESCRIPTOR is optional is null

    In run(ENT 23) file name (FC018_s_6_sequence_L70.txt) mentioned is not found among the submitted files

    In run(WS 23) file name (FC018_s_6_sequence_L70.txt) mentioned is not found among the submitted files
```

Please could someone suggest the retrieving method/option.

Comment: They say in Nokogiri documentation to use doc = Nokogiri::Slop <<<

But I am unable to use it as it throws me an error. any ideas

Comment: I found this from the internet:
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("myFile.xml").read)
# get elements with attribute:
elements = @doc.xpath("//*[@*[success]]")
# get just the attribute:
attributes = @doc.xpath("//@*[success]")

But still comes empty

Comment: Stay away from Slop. As noted in the footnotes at the bottom of [this document](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#fn:1): _"Don’t use this. … No, really, don’t use this. If you use it, don’t report bugs. … You’ve been warned!"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's not clear to me what you are trying to do, or what your problem is. Below are a variety of answers that might help.*

For any element you can use [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#attributes`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-attributes) to get a hash mapping the name of the node to a [`Nokogiri::XML::Attr`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Attr.html) (which has a `.value` you can read):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'erb'

template = <<ENDERB
<% unless @expts.empty? %>
<h3>Experiments</h3>
<ul><% for expt in @expts %>
  <li><%= expt %><ul>
    <% expt.attributes.each do |name,attr| %>
      <li><%=name%> = <%=attr.value%></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul></li>
<% end %></ul>
<% end %>
ENDERB

doc = Nokogiri.XML(DATA)
@expts = doc.xpath("//EXPERIMENT")   
puts ERB.new(template).result(binding).gsub(/^[ \t]*\n/,'')
#=> <h3>Experiments</h3>
#=> <ul>
#=>   <li><EXPERIMENT alias="ENT 23" status="PUBLIC"/><ul>
#=>       <li>alias = ENT 23</li>
#=>       <li>status = PUBLIC</li>
#=>   </ul></li>
#=>   <li><EXPERIMENT alias="WS 23" status="PUBLIC"/><ul>
#=>       <li>alias = WS 23</li>
#=>       <li>status = PUBLIC</li>
#=>   </ul></li>
#=> </ul>
```

Instead of `attributes` (a Hash) you can also use [`.attribute_nodes`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-attribute_nodes), which gives you a straight array of `Attr`s (with a `.name` and `.value` each).

Alternatively, while iterating through your experiment elements you could use…

```
<%= expt['alias'] %>
```

…to extract the value of a known attribute (returning a string such as `"ENT 23"`).

If you're trying to extract all the attributes on their own, you could also use…

```
@aliases = @doc.xpath('//@alias')
```

…if you wanted to get an array of just those attributes anywhere in the document (which have a `.name` and `.value`).

If you only want all the `alias` attributes on a particular element (e.g. `EXPERIMENT`) then you can use…

```
@expt_aliases = @doc.xpath('//EXPERIMENT/@alias')
```

Comment: Thank you Phrogz for your reply. Actually I can explain you the problem, I am basically trying to send some generated xml files to a third party web service which validates my xml and returns me a receipt in xml format which I provided above. from that xml I wanted to retrieve the success attribute and check whether it is true or false. This tells me whether my xmls are in the correct format or not. This way i could generate a page with the faults in it to the user to resubmit his/her data. I hope you got my idea. Thanks for the reply I got it to work though..! cheers